# Flutter http FormatException: Invalid number

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to post data to an endpoint(woocommerce create order). I use the following code to do this:

```
var data = {
        'customer_id': int.parse(Data.UserId),

        'billing[first_name]': nameInputController.text,
        'billing[phone]': phoneInputController.text,
        'billing[postcode]': postalCodeInputController.text,
        'billing[address_1]': addressInputController.text,

        'shipping[first_name]': nameInputController.text,
        'shipping[phone]': phoneInputController.text,
        'shipping[postcode]': postalCodeInputController.text,
        'shipping[address_1]': addressInputController.text,

        'customer_note': note,
      };

      var url = Uri.parse(Endpoints.completeOrder);
      var response = await http.post(url, body: data, headers: {
        'Authorization': Data.authToken
      });
```

but i get the following error:

```
I/flutter (25924): FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)
I/flutter (25924): 
I/flutter (25924): ^
```

When i replace `int.parse(Data.UserId)` with an string the problem is solved but i need to post customer_id as integer.

Comment: try `json.encode(data)`

Comment: @griffins i get the same error

Comment: `Data.UserId` is an empty string or contains only whitespace.  Either fix `Data.UserId` to have a legitimate value or check if `Data.UserId` is valid before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since if you replace it with `String` the error is removed, try `int.tryParse(Data.UserId).toString()` to see if it fixes your issue. I would suggest using `tryParse` instead of `parse` since you can get a `null` default value if the `parse` fails.